# Run distributed tensorflow example with error

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed

I have three node to run a distributed tensorflow, which is two worker(one has GPU,one not)and one ps(without GPU).The code is below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import time

# cluster specification
parameter_servers = ["192.168.1.102:2222"]
workers = [ "192.168.1.103:2223", 
      "192.168.1.104:2224"]
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps":parameter_servers, "worker":workers})

# input flags
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "Either 'ps' or 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

# start a server for a specific task
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, 
                      job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                      task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

# config
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 20
logs_path = "/tmp/mnist/1"

# load mnist data set
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
  server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

  # Between-graph replication
  with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
    cluster=cluster)):

    # count the number of updates
    global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], 
                            initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0), 
                            trainable = False)

    # input images
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
      # None -> batch size can be any size, 784 -> flattened mnist image
      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x-input")
      # target 10 output classes
      y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="y-input")

    # model parameters will change during training so we use tf.Variable
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    with tf.name_scope("weights"):
      W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 100]))
      W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 10]))

    # bias
    with tf.name_scope("biases"):
      b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
      b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    # implement model
    with tf.name_scope("softmax"):
      # y is our prediction
      z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1)
      a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
      z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a2,W2),b2)
      y  = tf.nn.softmax(z3)

    # specify cost function
    with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
      # this is our cost
      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

    # specify optimizer
    with tf.name_scope('train'):
      # optimizer is an "operation" which we can execute in a session
      grad_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
      train_op = grad_op.minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
      # accuracy
      correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # create a summary for our cost and accuracy
    tf.scalar_summary("cost", cross_entropy)
    tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)

    # merge all summaries into a single "operation" which we can execute in a session 
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    print("Variables initialized ...")

  sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                        global_step=global_step,
                        init_op=init_op)

  begin_time = time.time()
  frequency = 100
  with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target) as sess:
    # create log writer object (this will log on every machine)
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

    # perform training cycles
    start_time = time.time()
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

      # number of batches in one epoch
      batch_count = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

      count = 0
      for i in range(batch_count):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # perform the operations we defined earlier on batch
        _, cost, summary, step = sess.run(
                    [train_op, cross_entropy, summary_op, global_step], 
                    feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
        writer.add_summary(summary, step)

        count += 1
        if count % frequency == 0 or i+1 == batch_count:
          elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
          start_time = time.time()
          print("Step: %d," % (step+1), 
                " Epoch: %2d," % (epoch+1), 
                " Batch: %3d of %3d," % (i+1, batch_count), 
                " Cost: %.4f," % cost, 
                " AvgTime: %3.2fms" % float(elapsed_time*1000/frequency))
          count = 0

     print("Test-Accuracy: %2.2f" % sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
     print("Total Time: %3.2fs" % float(time.time() - begin_time))
     print("Final Cost: %.4f" % cost)

  sv.stop()
  print("done")
```

I run the above code on my three node with instruction below in terminal:

```
pc-01$ python example.py --job-name="ps" --task_index=0 
pc-02$ python example.py --job-name="worker" --task_index=0 
pc-03$ python example.py --job-name="worker" --task_index=1
```

However, after the Variables initialized, I met a question that the terminal of worker always print :

```
I tensor flow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:193] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker:／job:worker/replica:0/task:0
```

and the terminal of ps don't proceed.
The IP of ps is 192.168.1.102, and the IP of the worker is 192.168.1.103,192.168.1.104,just like the code above.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Not knowing the IPs of your three nodes, I'm not sure of your problem. I suggest that all the jobs of your example running at one node and changing the hosts in your ClusterSpec to 'localhost' for debugging.

Comment: The IP of ps is 192.168.1.102, and the IP of the worker is 192.168.1.103,192.168.1.104.

Comment: When I run my example at one node, it can get the accuracy, but one get the result and then another accept. But when running on three computer still not work.

Comment: is the firewall on those machines allowing gRPC connections?

Comment: You can check the accessibility of ps/worker by telnet after you task started.

Comment: Thank you all. I have solve this problem, cause I installed different version of tensorflow in three computer.

Comment: @SteveShi, if you've truly solved this problem, you should still create it as an answer to this question and accept it. This will help people trying to understand this same error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I guess filtering out device should help here. Could you please try adding  device_filter to your session ?

```
        config = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=False,
        device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index])

with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=\config) as sess:
```

This should fix the issue.